# why output list is empty in my code in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Using Python 2.7 and trying to do simple tokenization on UTF-8 encoded files. The output of `a` seems a byte string, which is expected, since after `tk[0].encode('utf-8')`, it converts from Python `unicode` type to `str/byte`. My major confusion is why output of `b` is empty list? I think without encoding (I mean without calling `.encode('utf-8')`), it should be raw unicode character (e.g. I expect some Chinese character printed, as `1.txt` is UTF-8 encoded Chinese character file).

**Source code**,

```
import jieba

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with open('1.txt', 'r') as content_file:
        content = content_file.read()

    segment_list = jieba.tokenize(content.decode('utf-8'), mode='search')
    if segment_list is None:
        print 'segment is None'
    else:
        a = [tk[0].encode('utf-8') for tk in segment_list]
        b = [tk[0] for tk in segment_list]

        print a
        print b
```

** Output **,

```
['\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7', '\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xb8\x82', '\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xb8\x82', '\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3', '\xe6\xb7\xb1\xe5\x9c\xb3\xe5\xb8\x82', '\xe7\xa6\x8f\xe7\x94\xb0', '\xe7\xa6\x8f\xe7\x94\xb0\xe5\x8c\xba', '\xe6\xa2\x85\xe6\x9e\x97', '\xe6\x9e\x97\xe8\xb7\xaf', '\xe6\xa2\x85\xe6\x9e\x97\xe8\xb7\xaf', '\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7', '\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xb8\x82', '\xe6\xb5\xa6\xe4\xb8\x9c', '\xe6\x96\xb0\xe5\x8c\xba', '\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xb8\x82', '\xe4\xb8\x8a\xe6\xb5\xb7\xe5\xb8\x82\xe6\xb5\xa6\xe4\xb8\x9c\xe6\x96\xb0\xe5\x8c\xba', '\xe8\x80\x80\xe5\x8d\x8e', '\xe8\xb7\xaf', '\r\n']
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `jieba.tokenize()` returns a generator. A generator can be iterated over only once. Better do

```
    b = [tk[0] for tk in segment_list]
    a = [tk.encode('utf-8') for tk in b]
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, if I just need utf-8 encoded tk[0], I just need to use one line `a = [tk[0].encode('utf-8') for tk in segment_list]`?

Comment: Thanks Tim, mark your reply as answer. You know so much! :)